# Is cacert.pem unique to my computer?

Tags: security, ssl, rsa

I currently believe `cacert.pem` is a bunch of keys that I can use to check that the site I'm talking to is in fact the site its claiming to be. As such, if I sent someone a program that was dependent on `cacert.pem` I can just send them a version on my computer and this has no security threat to me.

The only security threat would be for them and that is if I sent them a phony `cacert.pem`.

Is this correct and am I safe sending the version of `cacert.pem` on my computer to another potentially untrusted person?

EDIT:

AS Steffen pointed out, `cacert.pem` could refer to any file. I was referring to in particular the one that is found in the `Requests` `Python` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which `cacert.pem` file you are talking about, but`/etc/ssl/cacert.pem` on BSD or the `/etc/ssl/certs` folder on Linux contain just a public list of trusted certificate agencies, which are used to verify trust for SSL connections. There is no secret in these files and usually they are not even system specific (although one might add or remove CAs to manage own trust settings).

But again, I don't know what your `cacert.pem` file contains, because there is no inherent semantic with this file name. If it contains also private keys you should definitely not give it to others.

Answer (score 0):

> The only security threat would be for them and that is if I sent them a phony cacert.pem.

[`cacert.pem`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) is a collection of Root CAs and Subordinate CAs used to certify a site or service.

The three threats here are:

1. You add your own CA, and then later MitM the connection
2. The wrong CA certifies the site or service, and an attacker then later MitM the connection
3. Your copy of `cacert.pem` is tampered in transit

(1) is less of a concern because it would require you to have a privileged network position, like on the same LAN or in the telecom infrastructure. You could add your own CA and the recipient would likely be no wiser.

(2) is a real problem. For example, we know Google is certified by *Equifax Secure Certificate Authority*. Equifax certifies a Subordinate CA called *GeoTrust Global CA*. And GeoTrust certifies a Google Subordinate CA called *Google Internet Authority G2*.

So the first problem with (2) is [Diginotar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DigiNotar) and recently [MSC Holdings](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2015/03/maintaining-digital-certificate-security.html) claimed to certify Google properties, which we know is wrong. They could pull it off because of the collection of Roots and Subordinates.

The second problem with (2) is related to the first. Because you trust, say, *Google Internet Authority G2*, Google can mint certificates for any domain, and not just their properties. The problem here is its an ***unconstrained*** Subordinate CA, and it was done because [it was too inconvenient](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1151348#c18).

(3) is simply an attack by a MitM. He can remove a needed certificate, which could result in a DoS. Or he could insert a CA, which leads back to (1). or he could corrupt the whole file.