# OpenSSL connection error SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO, but browser and curl works

Tags: ssl, openssl

I'm dealing with an issue where python can't connect to a specific server over ssl due to openssl not being able to complete the handshake. Curl and my browser work. I've tried a couple of different openssl versions and [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538542/tlsv1-alert-internal-error-during-handshake), but can't seem to connect.

Here is what I've tried on both of the following platforms. The output is printed slightly different on OpenSSL 1.0.1e, but it's still the same errors.

```
Mac OSX Yosemite - OpenSSL 0.9.8zg 14 July 2015
Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy) - OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
```

Without specifying which version of

```
openssl s_client -connect www.uk-recruitment.net:443
openssl s_client -connect www.uk-recruitment.net:443 -cipher 'DEFAULT:!ECDH'
openssl s_client -connect www.uk-recruitment.net:443 -CAfile cacert.pem
openssl s_client -connect www.uk-recruitment.net:443 -CAfile cacert.pem -cipher 'DEFAULT:!ECDH'
openssl s_client -connect www.uk-recruitment.net:443 -CAfile cacert.pem -cipher 'DEFAULT:!ECDH' -servername uk-recruitment.net
```

but I always get the same result

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
66716:error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-52.40.1/src/ssl/s23_clnt.c:593:
```

If I add `-tls1`, `-tls1_1` or `-tls1_2` with all the same options, I get a slightly different error:

```
openssl s_client -connect www.uk-recruitment.net:443 -tls1
CONNECTED(00000003)
66750:error:14094438:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert internal error:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-52.40.1/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1145:SSL alert number 80
66750:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl handshake failure:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-52.40.1/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:566:
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The sites requires [Server Name Indication (SNI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) and SSL handshakes not using SNI will cause failure:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect www.uk-recruitment.net:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
139999237719712:error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error:s23_clnt.c:770:
```

With SNI instead it looks much better:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect www.uk-recruitment.net:443 -servername www.uk-recruitment.net
CONNECTED(00000003)
...
   Cipher    : ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
```

It might be that the `-servername` option is not available with OpenSSL 0.9.8, but it should be with OpenSSL 1.0.1.

Comment: Thanks, the flag shows as being available on 0.9.8, but still gave the same error (with both www prefix and not) so I assumed it wasn't the fix. Trying on 1.0.1 works.

Comment: Per ssllabs they are on cloudflare and require SNI, minimum TLSv1.0, *and ECDHE-ECDSA keyexchange*, and testing shows they also require "new-style" Hello (not SSLv2-compatible) which is the default for 0.9.8. 1.0.0 with `-servername` works, but 1.0.1 or 1.0.2 is better because they achieve TLSv1.2 and GCM. 0.9.8 can work using `-tls1 -ciphers ECCdraft:HIGH:!aNULL -servername`, but that's getting fiddly.