# SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, openssl, amazon-cloudfront

Currently running in a similar problem, but none of the solutions helps

- [OpenSSL connection error SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO, but browser and curl works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34187934/openssl-connection-error-ssl23-get-server-hello-but-browser-and-curl-works)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/649000/openssl-curl-error-ssl23-get-server-hellotlsv1-alert-internal-error

I do not have access to server configs as this is just a plain Cloudfront+S3 setup.

```
root@xxx:~# openssl s_client -connect tracking.kairion.de:443 -servername tracking.kairion.de
CONNECTED(00000003)
140336648943272:error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error:s23_clnt.c:757:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 318 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1480860654
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Curl is returning similar error

```
root@xxx:~# curl 'https://tracking.kairion.de/kairion.gif' -v
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 2400:cb00:2048:1::6818:72f8...
* Connected to tracking.kairion.de (2400:cb00:2048:1::6818:72f8) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error
```

Error is reproducible on at least two servers with:

```
openssl 1.0.1t-1+deb8u5 (jessie)
openssl 1.0.1t-1+deb7u1 (wheezy)
```

But works for

```
openssl 1.0.2j-1 (stretch)
```

Interesting part is sometimes it works for maybe an hour and then it fails for one hour.

Comment: You should probably use TLS 1.0 and above for the OpenSSL command. Try `openssl s_client -connect tracking.kairion.de:443 -servername tracking.kairion.de -tls1`. You can also use `-tls1_1` and `-tls1_2`. My OpenSSL is 1.1.0, so I cannot duplicate. OpenSSL 1.0.2 is also a good choice. OpenSSL 1.1.0 and 0.9.8 are bad choices since they lack a lot of the TLS features from the last several years.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: This question is indeed about development or did you forget that most of us will do command line tests while writing code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue today, was related to cloudflare.

Since I disabled cloudflare for this subdomain it works without a problem.

Seems like cloudflare returned sometimes the correct CNAME from cloudfront and sometimes the a cloudflare IP. As long as it returned cloudfront directly the SSL worked, when it returned the cloudflare IP the SSL failed.