# Boost SSL verifies expired and self-signed certificates

Tags: ssl, boost, openssl, ssl-certificate, boost-asio

I'm using Boost's asio to connect to a site via HTTPS. I want this to only succeed if the certificate is valid, not expired, not self-signed, etc. Unfortunately it seems to always work regardless. Here is my code:

```
try
{
    asio::io_service ioService;
    asio::ssl::context sslContext(asio::ssl::context::sslv3_client);

    sslContext.load_verify_file("cacert.pem");

    asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(ioService);
    asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query("self-signed.badssl.com", "443");
    asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpointIterator = resolver.resolve(query);

    boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket(ioService, sslContext);

    ioService.run();

    // Enable SSL peer verification.
    socket.set_verify_mode(asio::ssl::verify_peer | asio::ssl::verify_fail_if_no_peer_cert);

    asio::connect(socket.lowest_layer(), endpointIterator);

    socket.handshake(asio::ssl::stream_base::client);

    boost::asio::streambuf request;
    std::ostream requestStream(&request);
    requestStream << "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    requestStream << "Host: self-signed.badssl.com\r\n";
    requestStream << "Accept: */*\r\n";
    requestStream << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";

    asio::write(socket, request);
```

And so on. If I use `set_verify_callback()` and return `false` from the callback, the connection does fail, but `preverified` always seems to be true, even for https://self-signed.badssl.com/. Surely that isn't right?

Comment: Weirdness. I'll keep an eye on this post just in case someone else spots the real cause here. Amazing. Leaning something new everydsay

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue here is [Server Name Indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) (SNI):

> Server Name Indication (SNI) is an extension to the TLS computer
>   networking protocol by which a client indicates which hostname it is
>   attempting to connect to at the start of the handshaking process. This
>   allows a server to present multiple certificates on the same IP
>   address and TCP port number and hence allows multiple secure (HTTPS)
>   websites (or any other Service over TLS) to be served off the same IP
>   address without requiring all those sites to use the same certificate.

The badssl.com server is sending a certificate with a proper chain when you connect with no SNI. If you connect with SNI then the self-signed certificate will be sent. You can verify this with OpenSSL on the command line by observing the difference between the two commands:

```
openssl s_client -connect self-signed.badssl.com:443 -showcerts
openssl s_client -connect self-signed.badssl.com:443 -servername self-signed.badssl.com -showcerts
```

`boost::asio` has no API to add SNI, but I think you can do it by using the underlying OpenSSL API and the [native_handle()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__stream/native_handle.html) method on your stream. It should be something like this:

```
SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(socket.native_handle(), "self-signed.badssl.com");
```

I do note that you are configuring your context with `sslv3_client`. As SNI is a TLS extension (i.e. not SSLv3), this may not work without configuring a TLS context.

Comment: I'm glad I learned this. I had figured that it had to be in the protocol negotation/handshake phase. But this was new to me. Very useful information.

Comment: @sehe It's a rare day when I know something that you don't. And while I did know the solution, to be honest I wouldn't have understood the problem without your answer.

Comment: Ah I see! And yeah I noticed that `sslv3_client` isn't right.

Answer (score 2):

Well this is weird.

Obviously that server should be serving a self-signed certificate.

When checking with a browser or this online tool: https://www.digicert.com/help/ this is even confirmed. It shows the certificate is:

```
SHA1 Thumbprint = 079B3259D07C4DE2A1CE0EF4A5B5599D3B2D62EA
```

However, when I tried from my shell using e.g.

```
 openssl s_client -connect self-signed.badssl.com:443 -debug |&
      openssl x509 -text -noout
```

We get a clearly different cert with a "real" issuer: `Issuer: C=GB, ST=Greater Manchester, L=Salford, O=COMODO CA Limited, CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA`.

We clearly get a different cert:

```
SHA1 Fingerprint=C8:67:8E:DB:FD:BB:30:B5:3F:2D:7B:F9:66:B8:14:C6:2E:95:92:CE
```

When I added a callback to your code snippet:

```
auto cb = [](bool preverified, boost::asio::ssl::verify_context& ctx) {
    char subject_name[256];
    X509* cert = X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert(ctx.native_handle());
    X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), subject_name, 256);

    std::cout << "SSL Verify: " << subject_name << "\n";

    return preverified;
};
socket.set_verify_callback(cb);

asio::connect(socket.lowest_layer(), endpointIterator);
std::cout << "Connected: " << socket.lowest_layer().remote_endpoint() << "\n";

system::error_code ec;
socket.handshake(asio::ssl::stream_base::client, ec);

std::cout << "Shook hands: " << ec.message() << "\n";
```

I saw this was indeed the certificate ASIO was handling for me:

```
Connected: 104.154.89.105:443
SSL Verify: /C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
SSL Verify: /C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
SSL Verify: /C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
SSL Verify: /OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL Wildcard/CN=*.badssl.com
Shook hands: Success
```

I honestly have no idea how the two can be disagree - even when the IP address appears to resolve to the same. But this certainly seems to be relevant to the symptoms.