# Server returned [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error

Tags: ssl, rss, ssl-certificate, feed

I'm try to validate my feed
https://www.specificfeeds.com/techcrunch on  https://validator.w3.org/feed/, http://feedvalidator.org/ and http://www.rssboard.org/rss-validator/

I got error message
            Server returned [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error

but if i try this feed on my development server http://clone.specificfeeds.com/techcrunch2 then its working fine.

I have done lots of research for this but they can't help me so please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538542/tlsv1-alert-internal-error-during-handshake