# error:14094438:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert internal error,stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1

Tags: ssl-certificate

We Are Config SSl certificate in our server then after this error message is coming. How to resolve this issue

stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14094438:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert internal error

Comment: I am facing the same issue while connecting to APNS

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["tlsv1 alert internal error" during handshake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538542/tlsv1-alert-internal-error-during-handshake)

Comment: I would suggest you to inspect the TLS handshake with Wireshark and decrypt (if needed) the encrypted data using the technique in https://wiki.wireshark.org/TLS#Using_the_.28Pre.29-Master-Secret.

Answer (score -1):

Similar error came while connecting spark mongo..

At mongo server end it was giving error like this  SSL: error:14094438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error

There was the same problem with me when we were trying to connect mongo db with spark locally on spark.

Few things to check make sure your spark command is correct. 
 i)spark-submit --master local[8] --class  
--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore= 
--driver-java-options -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=

ii) also check the mongo configuration of the server i used below 
net:
 bindIp: 0.0.0.0,localhost
 port: 27017
 ssl:
  mode: requireSSL
  PEMKeyFile: test-server1.pem
  disabledProtocols: TLS1_0,TLS1_1

Issue for us was that we were using CAFile: /etc/ssl/caToValidateClientCertificates.pem property in mongo file . So the CA certificate of java trust store was not matching with the java one.

Make sure also if CA certs are matching . if not then remove the line of CAFile:  from mongo .